# Optimising javascript onclick function that copies data from input field

Tags: javascript, html, copy, clipboard, input-field

I have a javascript function that copies information from a text input field to the clipboard, which functions just fine. However, I need this function to be able to handle multiple inputs or connect multiple onclick events to the same input field.

Basically, I'm looking for ways to optimise the following.

```
function h1Function() {
var copyText1 = document.getElementById("h1Input");
copyText1.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
alert("Copied the text: " + copyText1.value);
}
function h2Function() {
var copyText2 = document.getElementById("h2Input");
copyText2.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
alert("Copied the text: " + copyText2.value);
}
```

connected to the following html fields.

```
<h1><a href="#" onclick="h1Function()">abcdefg123456ABCDEFG - h1</a></h1>
<input type="text" value="<div class='h1 highlight'>Din tekst her</div>" 
id="h1Input" />
<h2><a href="#" onclick="h2Function()">abcdefg123456ABCDEFG - h2</a></h2>
<input type="text" value="<div class='h2 highlight'>Din tekst her</div>" 
id="h2Input" />
```

Any and all optimization tips will be appreciated

Comment: Pass the `input`'s `id` as a parameter to the `h1Function()`

Comment: This should be posted on codereview.stackexchange.com as that is a much more suitable location for enhancement requests.

Comment: Since the two functions do the same thing, just on different elements, you only need one function and you can just use `this.parentElement.nextElementSibling` instead of the element references.

Comment: You also shouldn't be using hyperlinks that don't navigate anywhere just as a "hook" into some JavaScript. You can add a `click` event handler to any visible element, so you could just make the `h1` have the `onclick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the id as a parameter to the function.

```js
function h1Function(id) {
  var copyText1 = document.getElementById(id);
  copyText1.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText1.value);
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <a href="#" onclick="h1Function('input1')">abcdefg123456ABCDEFG - h1</a>
</h1>
<input type="text" id="input1" value="<div class='h1 highlight'>Din tekst her</div>" 
id="h1Input" />
<h2>
  <a href="#" onclick="h1Function('input2')">abcdefg123456ABCDEFG - h2</a>
</h2>
<input type="text" id="input2" value="<div class='h2 highlight'>Din tekst her</div>" 
id="h2Input" />
```

Comment: I will give you the correct answer, however i will add that i have also included Scott Marcus solution of adding the onclick event to the element instead of a dead link.